# vb 2008 webbrowser alternative

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, browser

hello i'm using `Visual Basic 2008 Express`
is there another webbrowsers such as `gekoWebBrowser`, but with less files, or is it possible to change default browser used by Visual Basic, from IE to Opera, chrome, firefox..

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: better speed for flash objects, browsing speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `WebBrowser` control included with WinForms is always going to use Internet Explorer (IE) as its rendering agent. It calls the native library `shdocvw.dll`. There is no way to change that. However, upgrading your computer's version of IE *will* upgrade the rendering agent used by the control.

Lots of people don't like being stuck with IE, however, and for very good reason. There are some alternative web browser controls for the .NET Framework. They are essentially wrappers for the rendering engines used by other browsers. Here are a couple of examples:

- **[WebKit .NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/)** is a wrapper for the WebKit engine, used by Google Chrome and Apple Safari.
- **[GeckoFX](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/)** is a wrapper for the Gecko rendering engine, used by Mozilla Firefox.
- **[MozNet](http://se7en-soft.com/moznet/)** is an alternative wrapper for Gecko that claims to be more active than GeckoFX.

Comment: FYI, MozNet is commercial software.