# Visual Studio WebBrowser and iCloud.com

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser, icloud

This is my second post on this topic as the first post I got no help with. I don't know if anyone knows how to help me, but I have searched and searched and I cannot figure out how to fix this problem that I have been trying to overcome for 4 days now. I have made a simple web browser that needs to load iCloud.com when a button is pressed. When I try to load the page, it tells me the web browser is not supported. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I am programming it in C#. I have everything fully updated and I have also tried to use different browsers such as Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer. I can load this page outside of VS with all of these browsers, but inside VS it will not work. My program can load every other page I throw at it except iCloud.com. If I try and load YouTube.com I get this: ("You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer 7 web browser. YouTube is ending support for Internet Explorer 7 soon, update your browser now.") I don't know how to change the browser version inside of VS. Can anyone point me in a direction that will help me? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I asked over at the microsoft visual studio forums if the browser control was updated and got no answer.

I'm using VS2010 Pro, have used VS2011 preview and VS2012 RC. There is no updated browser control in any of them, all report as IE7.

I would look for an alternative solution.

A few are listed here on SO [vb 2008 webbrowser alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692221/vb-2008-webbrowser-alternative/5692272#5692272)

Many also recommend [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)

If you must use the visual studio control I found some interesting discussion
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control) but it requires modifying the registry and specific system IE browsers.

Comment: Thank you for posting and trying to help! I see people using IE9 with visual studio 2010, but I can't seem to figure out how they are doing it. I will look into what you have posted and I will let you know if it worked for me. Thanks again mate! I have tried the GeckoFX solution with no avail. I will look into the WebKit.Net and see what happens. What confuses me is that you can download the extension bar to change the default browser in VS, but when I do this it still forces IE7.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Awesomium link!!!! It worked like a charm!!! You sir are my hero!!

Comment: Okay so now that I have it loading iCloud and working it will not work with Facebook or Youtube. It will load Facebook, but when I log in it will not display my page. It will only display the Facebook header. it shows the drop down button you use to select log out, but when it is click it takes me to my account settings. It will not bring up the actual drop down menu.

Comment: I'm going to go to another control shortly myself. Fortunately I'm not pressed on the reporting user agent right now but in the near future it's time to change controls.  Glad to help a bit, take care

Comment: I got around this by using the default web browser along with awesomium. Browser1 would be awesomium and browser2 would be the default and I just coded it like (Browser1.loadURL("Http://iCloud.com") Browser1.BringToFront(); and the same for browser 2. So when the buttons are click it brings either browser 2 the front.